# Dataframe Generator Based On Conditions Pandas

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have manually created a bunch of dataframes to later concatenate back together based on a list of bigrams I have(my reason for doing this is out of the scope of this question).  The problem is, I want to set this code to run daily or weekly and the manually created dataframes I have created will no longer work if the data has changed once refreshed.  For instance, looking at the code below, what if "data_science," is no longer a bigram being pulled from my code next week and I have another bigram like "hello_world," that is not listed below in my code.  I need to set up one function that will do all of these for me.  I have about 50 dataframes I am making from my real data so even without the automation purposes, it would be a huge time saver to get a function going for this.  One KEY point to make is that I am grabbing all of these bigrams from a list and naming a dataframe for each one of them.  My function below with the list_input is what I am using that for.

````
   data_science = df[df['column_name'].str.contains("data") & 
   df['column_name'].str.contains("science")]
   data_science['bigram'] = "(data_science)"

   p_value = df[df['column_name'].str.contains("p") & 
   df['column_name'].str.contains("value")]
   p_value['bigram'] = "(p_value)"

   ab_testing = df[df['column_name'].str.contains("ab") & 
   df['column_name'].str.contains("testing")]
   ab_testing['bigram'] = "(ab_texting)"```


I am trying something like this code below but have not figured out how to make it work yet.
```def df_creator(a,b, my_list):
    for a,b in my_list:
        a_b = df[df['Message_stop'].str.contains(a) & 
        df['Message_stop'].str.contains(b)]
        a_b['bigram'] = "(a_b)"```
````

Comment: Is your input variable `list_input` or is it `my_list`?

Comment: they are the same thing.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I will correct it.

Comment: any ideas on this one @G.Anderson?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of a specific solution, but common NLP packages like NLTK have n-gram functions, so you might find something in there that you could use with `df.apply()`

Comment: ok thanks for your help! :)